# Pass multiple value for a function in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is sample query which I am trying to implement and the idea is, the query should return the values fetched by 3 queries out of which two queries have functions in WHERE clauses.

```
SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T1 WHERE T1.X= 8755 UNION
SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T1 WHERE ISDESCENDANT(T1,8755) UNION
SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T1 WHERE ISANCESTOR(T1,8755)
```

The above query is working fine but, I want to replace the static value 8755 with another query's output. Something like,

```
SELECT Y FROM T1 WHERE T1.Z='Some_Name';
```

For example if the above query returned **4 values (8755,8766,8788,8799)** then these following queries should be executed.

```
SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T1 WHERE T1.X= 8755 UNION
SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T1 WHERE ISDESCENDANT(T1,8755) UNION
SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T1 WHERE ISANCESTOR(T1,8755)

SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T1 WHERE T1.X= 8766 UNION
SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T1 WHERE ISDESCENDANT(T1,8766) UNION
SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T1 WHERE ISANCESTOR(T1,8766)

SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T1 WHERE T1.X= 8788 UNION
SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T1 WHERE ISDESCENDANT(T1,8788) UNION
SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T1 WHERE ISANCESTOR(T1,8788)

SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T1 WHERE T1.X= 8799 UNION
SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T1 WHERE ISDESCENDANT(T1,8799) UNION
SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T1 WHERE ISANCESTOR(T1,8799)
```

Is there any way i could implement this? 
Please help me.

Comment: Just a minor note, duplicates are removed by UNION, so the DISTINCTs are redundant.

Comment: What are `isdescendant` and `isancestor` doing? You seem to be passing the table alias as an argument to a function, which is... um... clever. Maybe you can show some sample data and expected results too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T1 JOIN T1 AS T2 ON T1.X = T2.Y WHERE T2.Z = 'Some Name' UNION
SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T1 JOIN T1 AS T2 ON ISDESCENDANT(T1,T2.Y) WHERE T2.Z = 'Some Name' UNION
SELECT DISTINCT X FROM T1 JOIN T1 AS T2 ON ISDESCENDANT(T1,T2.Y) WHERE T2.Z = 'Some Name'
```